# How to manage entity mutation (form edit) with Redux and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, redux, react-redux

What is the best pattern to manage working copy (editable form) of an entity with Redux and React? I typically use the following architecture to manage forms:

```
           Redux
           ^    |
  Dispatch |    | Provides
  Actions  |    | list of entities
           |    V
  <EntitiesContainerComponent />
           ^    |
           |    |
  Identity |    | Maps to 
           |    V
    <Entitycomponent entity={e}
        doSave={(e) => this.handleSave(e)} />
```

Redux stores domain entities in [normalized](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape) form. Entities container receives list of particular entity type from Redux 
during it's mount by dispatching`GET_ENTITIES_FOO` action, and may persist a particular entity with Redux by dispatching `POST_ENTITY_FOO` action with the entity as payload.

Still, entities container maps and renders the list of entities to entity components (forms). Entity component is injected with identity entity and container callbacks (particularly save) as props. Entity component use callbacks as a function of it's identity entity.

Further, entity component copies the identity entity in it's internal state during mount. Form actions mutates the internal state of the entity component (entity working copy). Validation logic also validates the working copy. Finally, entity component will call save callback function with the working copy, which will ultimately reach Redux via container component.

Is this a good pattern, or should I explore some other patterns for Redux entities to forms?

Comment: One issue I can see in this approach is, you will have to bleed UI related data in store if nay components are dependent. Though it's not a big issue, ideally store should have entity data, not state.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: `Store` is suppose to store data of fields which is used for server communication and defined values for UI. `state` is something we store at individual component as its a UI related data. But if you have dependent components, you will have to store this UI state in store, so that we can share between components.